# C++ Pointer within parentheses

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a bit confused about this syntax.

```
void function ( float (*points)[2]);
```

Is this declaring an array of float pointers? If so, why the following code returns an error:

```
void foo( float (*points)[2]) {}

float *p[2];
foo(p); // error

float (*p)[2];
foo(p); // okay
```

Why do you need the parentheses?

Comment: `float (*points)[2]` is a pointer on an array of 2 float.

Comment: What's the same? Array and pointer to array? Of course, not.

Comment: @Jarod42 why do you need the parentheses?

Comment: @GiuseppePes Otherwise it would be an array of pointers, like the first one.

Comment: If you are getting confused with this then [this website](http://cdecl.org/) is a great c type -> English converter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`float *p[2]` defines an array of `float*`, with size 2.

`float (*p)[2]` defines a pointer to an array of `float`, with size 2:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    float* p[2];
    p[0] = new float(0.0);
    p[1] = new float(1.0);
    std::cout << *(p[0]) << " , " << *(p[1]) << "\n";

    float Q[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    float(*q)[2] = &Q;
    std::cout << (*q)[0] << " , " << (*q)[1] << "\n";

    delete p[0];
    delete p[1];
}
```

Notice that if the sizes of `Q` and `q` doesn't match, you get an error:

```
float Q[3] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };
float(*q)[2] = &Q; //error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float (*)[3]' to 'float (*)[2]'
```

Comment: What happens if `Q` was of size 3?

Comment: In this case, you get `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'float (*)[3]' to 'float (*)[2]'` on the assignment `float(*q)[2] = &Q`

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer to an array of two float values. Its practical purpose is an ability to pass a 2-D array with one dimension fixed to 2:

```
float data[][2] = {{1.2, 3.4}, {5.6, 7.8}, {9.1, 10.2}};
foo(data);
```

Typically a function like that would also take the overall size of the array.

Alternatively, a function like that could be used to allocate an array of two floats, and set the pointer to the result of allocation.